# Add automatically HTTPS if it's not a subdomain.

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, https

My website (https://www.went.digital) have a wildcard subdomain <sub>(but sadly **not** a wildcard SSL)</sub>, which redirects to a subfolder. That's mean that if you enter to `demo.went.digital`, you'll see what's in `went.digital/subdomain`. It doesn't really matter how does it work, but I'm saying it because **the `.htaccess` file affecting the subdomains too.**

I add into the `.htaccess` file code that automatically adds `www` if it's not a subdomain, and I add to it `https://` but it doesn't add the `https://` if you entered using `www`. 
Here is my current code in the `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to add a separate rule for that:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.went\.digital$ [NC]   
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.went.digital/$1 [L,R=301]
```